# Decomposition of a semialgebraic set into connected components

Tags: polynomials, computational-geometry

Is there any built-in function for doing decomposition of a semialgebraic set into connected components? The only way I now can think of is to use

```
CylindricalAlgebraicDecomposition
```

and to build connected componnets from its output: all terms connected with disjunction on first level are treated as vertexes of graph, two vartexes are connected if `Length[FindInstance[v1 && v2, {vars}]] != 0`. On produced graph usual depth-first search based algorithm is used. But intuition says that such things are usually already implemented, hence the question.

Comment: Are you looking for `SemialgebraicComponentInstances`?

Comment: @Artes No, as I understand `SemialgebraicComponentInstances` will give me at least one point from each connected component, but I need components themselves.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**: `CylindricalDecomposition` has been improved since I wrote this answer, probably in v11.2! Now it takes an optional topological operation argument. As a result, one can achieve the results described as `connected` below simply by adding such an argument to `CylindricalDecomposition`:

```
  decomp = List @@ BooleanMinimize@CylindricalDecomposition[eqns, {x, y},
                                                            "Components"];
```

---

The code below is a bit of a cheat: it modifies sets acquired through cylindrical decomposition by converting `<` to `<=` and `>` to `>=`. This prevents some infinitesimally small gaps from being recognised as such, but wins the possibility of finding overlaps between cylindrical cells produced by CAD. It may still serve as a starting point for more "real-world" solutions.

This code constructs a pairwise graph from those DNF components of the decomposition for which their closed region overlaps with another. From this connected graph components are computed, and this gives more or less directly connected components you seek:

```
Module[{eqns, decomp, connected, regdim},
 eqns = x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 >= 1/2 &&
   ! (0 <= y - x/2 <= 1/4) && ! (0 <= y/2 + x <= 1/4) &&
   x^2 + (y + 3/4)^2 >= 1/32;

 regdim = 
  RegionDimension@ImplicitRegion[Reduce[#, {x, y}, Reals], {x, y}] &;

 decomp = 
  List @@ BooleanMinimize@CylindricalDecomposition[eqns, {x, y}];

 connected = 
  Or @@@ ConnectedComponents@
    Graph[decomp, UndirectedEdge @@@
      Select[Subsets[decomp, {2}], 
       regdim[And @@ # //. {Less -> LessEqual, Greater -> GreaterEqual}] >= 0 &]];

 (Quiet@RegionPlot[#, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100] & /@
   {decomp, connected})~Join~
   {FullSimplify[connected, (x | y) \[Element] Reals]}]
```

The result shows CAD result, "unified" connected components and each component:

[image]

> {(Sqrt[1 - x^2] + y >= 
>        0 && ((x > 2 y && 2/Sqrt[5] + x > 0 && 
>           Sqrt[6] + 5 x <= 1) || (Sqrt[6] + 5 x > 1 && 
>           Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huEbi.png) + 8 x <= 0 && 
>           Sqrt[2 - 4 x^2] + 2 y <= 1) || (x < 1/Sqrt[5] && 2 x + y < 0 &&
>            8 x >= Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huEbi.png)) || (Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huEbi.png) + 8 x > 0 && 8 x < Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huEbi.png) && 
>           6 + Sqrt[2 - 64 x^2] + 8 y <= 0))) || (Sqrt[2 - 64 x^2] <= 
>        6 + 8 y && ((8 x < Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huEbi.png) && 2 x + y < 0 && 
>           10 x >= 1) || (Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huEbi.png) + 8 x > 0 && 10 x < 1 && 
>           Sqrt[2 - 4 x^2] + 2 y <= 1))), (1 + x == 0 && 
>       y == 0) || (Sqrt[7] + 4 x == 0 && 
>       4 y == 3) || (Sqrt[1 - x^2] >= 
>        y && ((1 + 2 Sqrt[19] + 10 x == 0 && 
>           Sqrt[1 - x^2] + y > 0) || (Sqrt[1 - x^2] + y >= 0 && 
>           1 + x > 0 && 
>           1 + 2 Sqrt[19] + 10 x < 0) || (1/Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huEbi.png) + x > 0 && 
>           Sqrt[7] + 4 x < 0 && 
>           1 + Sqrt[2 - 4 x^2] <= 2 y) || (1 + 2 Sqrt[19] + 10 x > 0 && 
>           1 + 2 x < 4 y && 1/Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huEbi.png) + x <= 0))) || (1/Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huEbi.png) + x > 0 &&
>        1 + 2 x < 4 y && Sqrt[2 - 4 x^2] + 2 y <= 1), (x == 1 && 
>       y == 0) || (Sqrt[1 - x^2] + y >= 
>        0 && ((Sqrt[1 - x^2] >= y && x > 2/Sqrt[5] && 
>           x < 1) || (10 x > 2 + Sqrt[19] && 5 x < 1 + Sqrt[6] && 
>           Sqrt[2 - 4 x^2] + 2 y <= 1) || (x > 2 y && 
>           5 x >= 1 + Sqrt[6] && x <= 2/Sqrt[5]))) || (10 x <= 
>        2 + Sqrt[19] && 4 x + 2 y > 1 && 
>       Sqrt[2 - 4 x^2] + 2 y <= 1), (4 x == Sqrt[7] && 
>       4 y == 3) || (4 x > Sqrt[7] && 10 x < 7 && 
>       1 + Sqrt[2 - 4 x^2] <= 2 y && 
>       y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2]) || (1 + 2 x < 4 y && Sqrt[1 - x^2] >= y && 
>       10 x >= 7)}

**EDIT:**

Here's an improvement to the case of infitesimal gaps. Instead of just rewriting CAD cells to closures, we search for intersection of one cell with `RegionBoundary` of another. `RegionPlot` visualisation is not particularly pretty in this case (there's a single point connecting upper and lower left side now), but that's not a problem caused by the connected components code. This version has a drawback of being considerably slower than the original answer.

```
Module[{eqns, decomp, connected, regconn},
 eqns = x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 >= 1/2 &&
   ! (0 == y - x/2 && x != -3/4) && ! (0 == y/2 + x) && 
   x^2 + (y + 3/4)^2 >= 1/32;

 regconn = 
  Resolve@Exists[{x, y}, (x | y) \[Element] Reals, 
     RegionMember[
      RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[#1, {x, y}], 
       RegionBoundary@ImplicitRegion[#2, {x, y}]], {x, y}]] &;

 decomp = 
  List @@ BooleanMinimize@CylindricalDecomposition[eqns, {x, y}];

 connected = 
  Or @@@ ConnectedComponents@
    Graph[decomp, UndirectedEdge @@@
      Select[Subsets[decomp, {2}], 
       regconn @@ # || regconn @@ Reverse@# &]];

 (Quiet@RegionPlot[#, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
       PlotPoints -> 100] & /@ {decomp, connected})~Join~
  {FullSimplify[connected, (x | y) \[Element] Reals]}]
```

[image]

> ...

Comment: If you really want to stress it out, try a transcendental component! :)  (+1) -- I've often wanted to do this.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Do you mean transcendental functions in definitions of the set? That would be obviously outside the domain of semialgebraic sets which are at least somewhat easier to operate computationally...

Comment: In mathematics, we call your "expanded" components their [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, and yes I know it goes beyond the literal scope of the question.  It also sometimes will go beyond the capabilities of `Reduce`, which can be used instead of `CylindricalDecomposition`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Unless I'm mistaken, the benefit of `CylindricalDecomposition` in comparison to `Reduce` is that individual cells it produces are guaranteed to be connected.  In the case of `Reduce`, one "cell" (or for instance, DNF item) may present multiple disconnected components, and there's no trivial mechanical method of transforming them to connected cells like in CAD. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: I guess I don't know for sure.  I thought `Reduce[.., {x, y}]` produced a CAD with respect to `{x, y}`: "For polynomial systems, Reduce uses cylindrical algebraic decomposition for real domains...." -- [`tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm not surprised of this, but you definitely are not going to get separated connected components for some cyclic (of couse, non-semialgebraic) functions with plain old `Reduce` without tricks.

Comment: It could be why I gave up on this sort of thing in the past. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 This is long overdue, but regarding your comment on closures... An anecdote from Finnish television years ago: an established F1 commentator: "black smoke comes from nozzles behind his car!" - to which an old F1 driver in the studio laconically comments: "in professional circles we call them 'exhaust pipes.'" :}

I was feeling a bit like that guy. :)