# How to read complicated result from Reduce?

Tags: equation-solving, fundamentals

How can I read this `Reduce` output from Mathematica that I got from solving an inequality? I do not perfectly know when one case in this case analysis is over and the next starts. I can see the differentiation between $r<0$, $r=0$ and $r>0$ as well as for the different $p$-values, but then it gets tricky. Isn't there a nicer way to illustrate the result? I need a general answer since I will have to calculate many of these inequalities.

This is the result:

```
F \[Element] 
  Reals && ((r < 
      0 && ((p < 
          0 && ((F < 0 && (a < (p - F r)/(F r) || a > 0)) || (F == 0 &&
              a > 0) || (0 < F < p/(2 r) && 
             0 < a < (p - F r)/(F r)) || (p/(2 r) < F < p/
              r && (a < 0 || a > (p - F r)/(F r))) || (F > p/r && (
              p - F r)/(F r) < a < 0))) || (p > 
          0 && ((F < p/r && (p - F r)/(F r) < a < 0) || (p/r < F < p/(
              2 r) && (a < 0 || a > (p - F r)/(F r))) || (p/(2 r) < 
              F < 0 && 0 < a < (p - F r)/(F r)) || (F == 0 && 
             a > 0) || (F > 
              0 && (a < (p - F r)/(F r) || a > 0)))))) || (r == 
      0 && ((p < 0 && a > 0) || (p > 0 && a > 0))) || (r > 
      0 && ((p < 
          0 && ((F < p/r && (p - F r)/(F r) < a < 0) || (p/r < F < p/(
              2 r) && (a < 0 || a > (p - F r)/(F r))) || (p/(2 r) < 
              F < 0 && 0 < a < (p - F r)/(F r)) || (F == 0 && 
             a > 0) || (F > 
              0 && (a < (p - F r)/(F r) || a > 0)))) || (p > 
          0 && ((F < 0 && (a < (p - F r)/(F r) || a > 0)) || (F == 0 &&
              a > 0) || (0 < F < p/(2 r) && 
             0 < a < (p - F r)/(F r)) || (p/(2 r) < F < p/
              r && (a < 0 || a > (p - F r)/(F r))) || (F > p/r && (
              p - F r)/(F r) < a < 0))))))
```

I tried to make a case analysis by typing in:

```
Reduce[(2*a*p*r*F - a*p^2)/((2*a + 2)*r^2*F^2 + (-2*a - 4)*p*r*F + 2*p^2) < 0]
```

Thankful for every help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Using Simplify[Reduce[...]] can sometimes make the result 30% smaller and thus possibly a little easier to read. Positioning your cursor just after a ( and giving a single mouse click highlights the matching pair of () and can thus help you determine when one case ends and the next starts. Thus you have four alternatives in your simplified result or three compound cases in your unsimplified result. Thank you for showing the Reduce[] that you used to get that result. That was very helpful in trying to provide you with some assistance.

Comment: `BooleanConvert[ ]`and `LogicalExpand[ ]` are sometimes useful to flatten the nested conditions. That doesn't mean that the expression will be "easy" to read, but at least you may focus in one condition at a time

Comment: Example `LogicalExpand@
 Reduce[(2*a*p*r*F - a*p^2)/((2*a + 2)*r^2*F^2 + (-2*a - 4)*p*r*F + 
      2*p^2) < 0, Reals]`

Comment: @Bill Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try the Simplify[] .
At belisarius Thanks a lot as well. Thanks for proposing BooleanConvert[] and LogicalExpand[].

Comment: @belisarius Thanks a lot as well. Thanks for proposing BooleanConvert[] and LogicalExpand[].Especially LogicalExpand[] seems very helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First thing to consider with such a convoluted expression is that there are many equivalent forms of it. `FullSimplify`, espectially with assumptions (or `Assuming`) can considerably reduce the size of output.

Some examples, although by any means all the flexibility, are represented below.

First, let's define a function which formats Boolean equations, rewritten into disjunctive normal form, with "simplest" forms first. Every row represents one item in `Or` ($a\lor b\lor c\lor\ldots$).

```
ClearAll[prettyDNF];

prettyDNF[eqns_] := 
 TraditionalForm@
  Column[SortBy[
    List @@ (FullSimplify /@
       BooleanMinimize[eqns, "DNF"]), 
    LeafCount],
   Dividers -> All]
```

A simple example:

```
prettyDNF[a || b && c]
```

$$\begin{array}{|l|}
\hline
 a \\
\hline
 b\land c \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Now you can show your output in slightly more understandable form:

```
prettyDNF[
 FullSimplify@
  Reduce[(2*a*p*r*F - a*p^2)/((2*a + 2)*r^2*F^2 + (-2*a - 4)*p*r*F + 2*p^2) < 0]]
```

$$\begin{array}{|l|}
\hline
 F\in \mathbb{R}\land p\neq 0\land
   r=0\land a>0 \\
\hline
 a>0\land F\leq 0\land p>0\land r>0 \\
\hline
 F\geq 0\land p<0\land a>0\land r>0 \\
\hline
 F\geq 0\land r<0\land a>0\land p>0 \\
\hline
 p<0\land r<0\land a>0\land F\leq 0 \\
\hline
 F>0\land p>0\land r<0\land p<(a+1) F r
   \\
\hline
 F>0\land p<0\land r>0\land (a+1) F r<p
   \\
\hline
 a<0\land r>0\land F r<p\land p<2 F r
   \\
\hline
 a<0\land r>0\land 2 F r<p\land p<F r
   \\
\hline
 a<0\land r<0\land p<F r\land 2 F r<p
   \\
\hline
 F<0\land p>0\land r>0\land p<(a+1) F r
   \\
\hline
 F<0\land p<0\land r<0\land (a+1) F r<p
   \\
\hline
 a<0\land a+1>\frac{p}{F r}\land
   p>0\land r>0 \\
\hline
 a<0\land p<0\land r<0\land
   a+1>\frac{p}{F r} \\
\hline
 a<0\land 2 F<\frac{p}{r}\land
   F>\frac{p}{r}\land p>0 \\
\hline
 F<\frac{p}{r}\land a+1>\frac{p}{F
   r}\land 2 F>\frac{p}{r} \\
\hline
 2 F<\frac{p}{r}\land a+1>\frac{p}{F
   r}\land F>\frac{p}{r} \\
\hline
 a+1<\frac{p}{F r}\land 2
   F<\frac{p}{r}\land a>0\land p>0\land
   r>0 \\
\hline
 a+1<\frac{p}{F r}\land 2
   F<\frac{p}{r}\land p<0\land r<0\land
   a>0 \\
\hline
 a+1<\frac{p}{F r}\land p<0\land
   a>0\land 2 F>\frac{p}{r}\land r>0 \\
\hline
 a+1<\frac{p}{F r}\land r<0\land
   a>0\land 2 F>\frac{p}{r}\land p>0 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

If you can use assumptions on your variables (let's assume `F > 0`), it may reduce number of forms radically:

```
Assuming[F > 0, 
 prettyDNF[
  FullSimplify@
   Reduce[(2*a*p*r*F - a*p^2)/((2*a + 2)*r^2*F^2 + (-2*a - 4)*p*r*F + 2*p^2) < 0]]]
```

$$\begin{array}{|l|}
\hline
 p<0\land a>0\land r>0 \\
\hline
 r<0\land a>0\land p>0 \\
\hline
 p\neq 0\land r=0\land a>0 \\
\hline
 a<0\land p<F r\land 2 F r<p \\
\hline
 a<0\land F r<p\land p<2 F r \\
\hline
 a+1<\frac{p}{F r}\land p<0\land r>0 \\
\hline
 a+1<\frac{p}{F r}\land r<0\land p>0 \\
\hline
 a<0\land a+1>\frac{p}{F r}\land
   p>0\land r>0 \\
\hline
 a<0\land p<0\land r<0\land
   a+1>\frac{p}{F r} \\
\hline
 a+1<\frac{p}{F r}\land 2
   F<\frac{p}{r}\land a>0 \\
\hline
 F<\frac{p}{r}\land a+1>\frac{p}{F
   r}\land 2 F>\frac{p}{r} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Also, there may be other rewriting methods than `FullSimplify` with `Assuming`. For instance, cylindrical algebraic decomposition (which may a have more intuitive geometric formulation) can be used on polynomials:

```
ClearAll[prettyDNF2];

prettyDNF2[eqns_] := 
 TraditionalForm@
  Column[SortBy[List @@
     BooleanMinimize[eqns, "DNF"], 
    LeafCount],
   Dividers -> All]

Assuming[F > 0,
 prettyDNF2[
  Refine@CylindricalDecomposition[
   (2*a*p*r*F - a*p^2)/((2*a + 2)*r^2*F^2 + (-2*a - 4)*p*r*F + 2*p^2) < 0,
   {F, r, p, a}]]]
```

$$\begin{array}{|l|}
\hline
 r=0\land a>0\land p>0 \\
\hline
 r=0\land p<0\land a>0 \\
\hline
 p<0\land a>0\land r>0 \\
\hline
 r<0\land a>0\land p>0 \\
\hline
 F r<p<2 F r\land a<0\land r>0 \\
\hline
 2 F r<p<F r\land a<0\land r<0 \\
\hline
 a<\frac{p-F r}{F r}\land p<0\land r>0
   \\
\hline
 a<\frac{p-F r}{F r}\land r<0\land p>0
   \\
\hline
 0<a<\frac{p-F r}{F r}\land p>2 F
   r\land r>0 \\
\hline
 0<a<\frac{p-F r}{F r}\land p<2 F
   r\land r<0 \\
\hline
 0<p<F r\land \frac{p-F r}{F
   r}<a<0\land r>0 \\
\hline
 F r<p<0\land \frac{p-F r}{F
   r}<a<0\land r<0 \\
\hline
 F r<p<2 F r\land a>\frac{p-F r}{F
   r}\land r>0 \\
\hline
 2 F r<p<F r\land r<0\land a>\frac{p-F
   r}{F r} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**EDIT:**

Some eye candy for two-dimensional toy case, for demonstration of the fact visualization is a very good way to make inequalities intuitive in two-dimensional cases:

```
Module[{eqns, sols},
 eqns = x^2 + y^2 < 1 && x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 > 1/2 && ! (0 < y - x/2 < 1/4); 
 sols = Assuming[(x | y) \[Element] Reals, 
   FullSimplify[List @@ BooleanMinimize[Reduce@eqns, "DNF"]]];
 RegionPlot[sols, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image]

Same with `GenericCylindricalDecomposition`, which generates only fully dimensional regions:

```
Module[{eqns, sols},
 eqns = x^2 + y^2 < 1 && x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 > 1/2 && ! (0 < y - x/2 < 1/4); 
 sols = List @@ 
   BooleanMinimize[
    First@GenericCylindricalDecomposition[eqns, {x, y}], "DNF"];
 RegionPlot[sols, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image]

It's worth noting the order of decomposition affects formulation of regions.

Comment: Wow. What can I say. This is a pretty awesome answer. Thanks a lot for all your effort. Very helpful as well. Should solve my problem with illustration.

Comment: Related in regard of recognizing connected components in semialgebraic sets: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83166/3056 . If a semialgebraic set consists of multiple connected components, this may help making results more understandable in smaller pieces.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an another approach on visualizing (two-dimensional) inequalities in a hierarchial fashion. It's certainly work in progress in many ways, but what can you expect from something hacked together while waiting for a flight... :)

(Interestingly enough `":"` and `TraditionalForm` works differently on these saved selections than on Mma. Oh well.)

**EDIT:** Improved `showRegion` thanks to rcollyer!

```
ClearAll[showRegion];

showRegion[eq_, vars_List, range_List] := 
 RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[eq, vars], PlotRange -> range, 
  FrameTicks -> None]


ClearAll[visualizeEquation];

visualizeEquation[e_And | e_Or | e_Xor, vars_List, range_List] := 
  Framed@OpenerView[{Row[{showRegion[e, vars, range], Spacer[20], 
        Head@e, ":", 
        Spacer[10], (Head@e) @@ (Framed /@ (List @@ e))}], 
      Column[visualizeEquation[#, vars, range] & /@ (List @@ e)]}, 
     True];
visualizeEquation[e_, vars_List, range_List] := 
  Framed@Row[{showRegion[e, vars, range], Spacer[20], e}];


visualizeEquation[
 Xor[x^2 + (y - 1/4)^2 <= 1, x^2 + (y + 1/4)^2 <= 1],
 {x, y},
 {{-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/2, 3/2}}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
visualizeEquation[
 Reduce@Xor[x^2 + (y - 1/4)^2 <= 1, x^2 + (y + 1/4)^2 <= 1], {x, 
  y}, {{-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/2, 3/2}}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` instead of `DiscretizeRegion` as it doesn't display the mesh. But, it requires that `RegionDimension` equal `RegionEmbeddingDimension`. So, I used `With[{reg = ImplicitRegion[eq, vars]},
 If[RegionDimension@reg  != RegionEmbeddingDimension@reg,
  DiscretizeRegion[reg, range],
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, range]
  ]
 ]` to switch back when it wasn't allowed.

Comment: @rcollyer Guess what was the thing I wrestled most on my hack? Displaying regions of dimension 0, 1 and 2 all in an acceptable manner. There's room for improvement in that regard in my code, but in my opinion also on facilities Mma provides.

Comment: Looking through it, I think `RegionPlot` is even better: `showRegion[eq_, vars_List, range_List] := 
 RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[eq, vars], PlotRange -> range, 
  FrameTicks -> None]`. Also, you can display multiple regions at once with it, which in most cases clarifies how they go together.

Comment: @rcollyer Huh! I tried to do this the "old way", using equation in `RegionPlot`. Apparently supplying region instead actually works! :)

Comment: welcome to version 10. The mini-bar is on your right, and world domination is just a quick bit of coding away. :)

Comment: @rcollyer While using your new and improved `RegionPlot` with `ImplicitRegion`s, I found a way to consistently crash the kernel, though, and discretization-based `RegionPlot`s also don't seem to obey `PlotPoints` (at least always). I hope these kinks get ironed out some day, then it's great!

Comment: just because there's some instability in the kernel ... I had a joke, but it's early.

Comment: @rcollyer I'm happy of `RegionPlot` working with geometric regions directly, and I actually now recall I found it better than the alternatives earlier when tinkering with new v10 functionality - and then forgot it. Sad to see it stumble on some other instances though. :/